# How to set a padding only for new lines of a textarea (while keeping the line-height constant)?

Tags: html, css

The goal is to have several lines in an HTML textarea that keep the line-height (e.g. 100%). However, when using enter and going to the next line, there should be a padding.

The suggestion to use `line-height:20px;` will have an effect on all lines. However, I need only a padding after a line break.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9bsu74fw/ ← It does apply the line-height to all lines. Not just the **line break**.

[image: screenshot fiddle textarea padding issue]

What is needed:

[image: textarea mockup]

How to achieve this with CSS?

Comment: are you using <br> for the particular line break? if yes, use a class for br and use padding for it

Comment: No, it's a standard HTML `<textarea>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::first-line` pseudo selector to apply style on first line only

```css
textarea::first-line {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for each line. Let's assume there are 10 separate lines.

Comment: so just normal `textarea { line-heght: 20px }` will work too

Comment: No, it does not, then it would be easy. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/9bsu74fw/ ← It does apply the line-height to all lines. Not just the **line break**.

Comment: then you probably need to use javascript for this i guess.

Comment: because default behaviour of html element is either wrap line (which breaks the line) and nowrap can create a scrollbar which is not our desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use as much `&nbsp;` between the paragraphs, until you get desired output.

`&nbsp;` is non-breaking space.

Comment: This will lead to non-breaking lines, see https://jsfiddle.net/c5ez306j/

Comment: Sorry, I think you do not understand the question. A `&nbsp;` creates a white space, no line break.